# Find a recursive relation for the case of a length $n$ binary string where there are no three consecutive $0$'s.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinations, binary

> Find a recursive formula for the following example. The number of binary strings of length $n$, such that there are no $3$ consecutive $0's$.

I started by considering the length $n$ as a block ($1$ row) with $n$ many columns. I started off by considering only the last column, marked $x$. Here's my working:

[image]

Int the case that the very last string is $0$, I think my working out is correct. Now, if the last string is $1$, then I'm left with $n-1$ without any further complications. Therefore, $a_n= 2a_{(n-1)}+a_{(n-2)}+a_{(n-3)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You are missing some $a$'s there in what you wrote.  Also, why does $2$ appear?

Comment: Where is the $2$? Do you mean the $n-2$?

Comment: You wrote $a_n = \color{red}{2}(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)$.  The $\color{red}{2}$ is what I am pointing to.  It looks like perhaps you were thinking it from both the $\dots x0$ case as well as the $\dots 1$ case, but the $\dots x 0$ case was already covered when you split it further into $\dots 1 00$ and $\dots 10$

Comment: AH. Yes sorry about that. The image doesn't contain the $n-1$ for the case where the last digit is $1$. Since that is also $n-1$, I simply simplified $(n-1)+(n-1)$ to $2(n-1)$.

Comment: Including it for the case of the last digit being $1$ is fine.  That accounts for one of the $(n-1)$'s... but where did the second one come from?  And really... this lack of $a$'s is getting frustrating.  Do you recognize the difference between writing $a_{n-1}$ and $(n-1)$?  You have $a_{n-1}$ is the number of valid sequences of length $n-1$.  On the other hand $(n-1)$ is not necessarily related to the counting problem at hand and is just the number one less than $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Critique**

The diagram in the question is correct, but the recursion drawn from it is slightly off. In the diagram, it is shown that each of the $a_n$ strings of length $n$ with out a '$000$' can be classified as follows:

**It ends in a '$\boldsymbol{1}$':$\phantom{00}$** $\overbrace{\boxed{\phantom{0\times\times\times\times000\times}}\boxed{\times\vphantom{0}}}^{n-1}\!\,\boxed{1\vphantom{\times}}$ There are $a_{n-1}$ of these.

**It ends in a '$\boldsymbol{10}$':$\phantom{0}$** $\overbrace{\boxed{\phantom{0\times\times00\times\times}}\boxed{\times\vphantom{0}}}^{n-2}\!\,\boxed{1\vphantom{\times}}\boxed{0\vphantom{\times}}$ There are $a_{n-2}$ of these.

**It ends in a '$\boldsymbol{100}$':** $\overbrace{\boxed{\phantom{0\times\times\times\times}}\boxed{\times\vphantom{0}}}^{n-3}\!\,\boxed{1\vphantom{\times}}\boxed{0\vphantom{\times}}\boxed{0\vphantom{\times}}$ There are $a_{n-3}$ of these.

Therefore, adding these cases up, we get
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\tag1
$$
In the question, it seems that the intermediate tree node, i.e. $\overbrace{\boxed{\phantom{0\times\times\times\times}}\boxed{\times\vphantom{0}}}^{n-1}\!\boxed{0\vphantom{\times}}$, is being included in the counting, but that node is counted in the leaves below it.

---

**Generating Function Approach**

Let $x$ represent the atom '$1$', $x^2$ represent the atom '$10$', and $x^3$ represent the atom '$100$'.

$\left(x+x^2+x^3\right)^k$ counts the strings made up of $k$ atoms; the coefficient of $x^n$ telling the how many strings of length $n$ can be made from $k$ atoms. After adding up the contributions from all numbers of the atoms, we handle the strings starting with '$0$' and '$00$' by multiplying by $\left(1+x+x^2\right)$ to get the generating function for the number of strings that can be made up from any number of atoms is
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(x+x^2+x^3\right)^k
&=\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x-x^4}{1-x}\right)^k\\
&=\left(1+x+x^2\right)\frac1{1-\frac{x-x^4}{1-x}}\\
&=\left(1+x+x^2\right)\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^4}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x-x^2-x^3}\\[9pt]
&=1+2x+4x^2+7x^3+13x^4+24x^5+\dots
\end{align}
$$
The denominator of $1-x-x^2-x^3$ gives the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$.

Comment: nicely done (+1)

Answer (score 0):

To gather the comments:

- You are leaving out the $a$'s.  There is a difference between the meaning of $a_{n-1}$ and the value $(n-1)$.  On the one hand $a_{n-1}$ is the number of valid length $n-1$ strings we are wanting to count.  On the other hand $(n-1)$ is merely the length of a length $n-1$ string... not the count of them.
- You have a rogue $2$ which appeared which shouldn't have, perhaps from reading your image incorrectly.  It feels like when you went to break into cases you broke into the case where the final digit was a $1$ which accounts for $a_{n-1}$ of the total, and where you broke into where the final digit was a $0$.  You broke this second case down into two further subcases of sizes $a_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-3}$ respectively and added...  It felt like maybe you accidentally added a value intended to be for the second case before it was broken into subcases as well but this was unnecessary as we were adding the values for the subcases already so it should already by covered.

Additionally:

- You haven't written any initial conditions yet.

For initial conditions, a tip: it can be easier to deal with zero as it is far more convenient.  You can work with as one of the initial conditions that $a_0 = 1$.  It is worth making sure you fully understand why $a_0=1$, that there *is* in fact a unique length zero valid string, namely `" "`.

If that is too abstract for you to accept (*though, you really should learn to come to terms with it sooner rather than later*), then go ahead and count with your fingers how many valid strings there are of length $1$, $2$, and $3$ manually.  I discourage this however as it can be easy to make a mistake, especially for larger harder problems.

The fact that "0" is a valid string of length $1$ is also worth taking into account as otherwise this might have been missed by the formula (*as I had done before my edit*).

So... our final answer should have read:

$$a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}~~~~~\text{for all }n>2\\a_0 = 1~~~~a_1 = 2~~~~~a_2=4$$